# How can I rebuild core utils for arm (Android)?

Tags: android, dd, gnu-coreutils

I'm working on a project, where I need to modify `dd` for Android, but I can't figure out how to build it. I've tried a simple way using `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc dd.c -o dd`, but of course that wouldn't work. And I also can't find a makefile.

Is it possible to just build `dd` or do I need to build `toolbox` or the whole system? In any case, how do I do that?

I found the source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.2.2_r1/toolbox/).

EDIT:
Is it possible to build the [GNU core utils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/coreutils.html) for `arm`? I tried using `./configure --host=arm-linux --target=arm-linux && make`, but `file dd` still returns `executable, x86-64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of googling I was finally able to build the GNU core utils for `arm`.

I first had to set the environment variables `CC` and `CXX` to `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` and `LDFLAGS` to `-static`. Then I just ran `./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux && make` and that's it.

Comment: This answer does not explain the difference between compiling coreutils for Linux and for Android. As currently presented, the coreutils built using this answer do not run on Android because they are linked against glibc, not Android's bionic libc. So the post does not answer the "(Android)" part of the question.

Comment: Gosh what a luck, I couldn't do that, `make` gave error right away because trying to run an ARM-compiled tool on my machine (`make-prime-list`)

Comment: "the coreutils built using this answer do not run on Android because they are linked against glibc, not Android's bionic libc"
I think most programs built this way can run on Android. Only very few are problematic.